# Load css stylesheet based on ID?

Tags: javascript, html

Hey how can I load a css stylesheet only based on id using javascript? Here is the code that I have:

```
<link id='bs-css' rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap-cyborg.css' type='text/css' />
```

I want to be able to use it only on the div that I want so something similar to this code:

```
<div id="bs-css"> 
some code 
</div>
```

I tried this code but its not functioning like I wanted, here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

if($("#bs-css").size()>0){
        if (document.createStyleSheet){
            document.createStyleSheet('bootstrap-cyborg.css');
        }
        else {
            $("head").append($("<link id='bs-css' rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap-cyborg.css' type='text/css' />"));
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

How can I load a css stylesheet only on the div that I want using an id and javascript?

Comment: In what way does your code "not function"?  Are there errors in the console? Does *anything* happen?

Comment: What do you mean by `I want to be able to use it only on the div that I want`? Your code should work properly in terms of detecting if the element is present. Although note that `.size()` was deprecated in version 1.8; you can use `.length` instead

Answer (score 2):

**Stylesheets** are not bound to element IDs. **CSS declarations** *within* the stylesheet are. There is little point attempting to load a stylesheet in code as you propose.

Simply making a declaration for the ID you are targetting within a typical stylesheet is the best way to do this.

Comment: See also the [`scoped` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#attr-style-scoped), not that it's [well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped).

Comment: @robertc Nice, never heard of that before

Comment: @robertc: scoped attribute has been removed and it has had very little support (only FF 54)